# Is there a fix for action extensions to appear consistently in a contextual menu (in the same context)?

Tags: macos, mojave, plugins, contextual-menu

I'm running macOS Mojave (10.14.6) and can’t seem to get action extensions to appear consistently in a contextual menu (right-click menu). One of the best-known action extensions is Apple's "Markup", which can be invoked on any image.

Now, I have an app called Clean Text which includes an action extension that can be invoked via contextual menu on a text selection in an app, and which includes filters that can strip extra spaces and returns. The problem is that when I invoke a contextual menu on a text selection, much more often than not, I see a standard contextual menu (with cut/copy/paste and services list), but not "Clean Text".

In case it helps with troubleshooting this, when this extension does appear, the contextual menu also indicates that there are 4 new ones with a badge, but opening System Preferences > Extensions > Actions does not corroborate this. Any idea how to troubleshoot?

Here is a screenshot taken from a different text-based app (Drafts), where the standard contextual menu appears:

> [image: standard contextual menu]

And here is the action menu that appears on the same text:

> [image: action menu]

Finally, here is what **System Preferences > Extensions > Actions** looks like. Notice no blue dots indicating newness?

[image: system preferences]